# Efficient way to use json DB

Tags: android, json

I'm writing an app that will have users and task for each user. Users can share exchange task between them. For this I am building a JSON online DB. My question is what is the most efficient way to do this? Create for each user json file, or one giant global json file that will hold all information. Another question is can android read only part of the online json file or it have to read all of it and then when the data stored locally on the device parse the needed section of the file?

Comment: u hv to aply pagination on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing all of the application's data in a giant file would make that giant file a serious bottleneck for the performance of your system.  Each time that you would need to write it, you would have to block all of the other tasks reading it while you perform the update.  To get around this, you would have to do some complicated processing to avoid race condition, which adds to unnecessary development work. Furthermore, if you ever decided to change the schema, you would have difficulty migrating the changes.

I would recommend using a relational database like MySQL, or perhaps NoSQL database like MongoDB in order to accomplish the task.  Furthermore, you could wrap the usage of these databases using an object-relational mapping library. There are a number of libraries that allow object-relational mapping as well, which would help you change the schema later on if you needed to; I am not familiar with the ones available for Android.

Alternatively, use the small json files to handle your information.  If this is for a school project it is probably possible to make a simple enough scheme without using a database.

Also, I think your question might be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead of Stack Overflow.